# How to obtain a variable from another python program?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have written a program using openCV and PIL to screen grab a section of my screen, perform template matching, draw where the template is found, and then display the image in a window. It's about 50 frames per second at this point, so it displays my real time desktop. Frames aren't a priority. The question then is how can I access the location variables in another program in real time?

I am relatively new to python, so I understand that this might be biting off a lot more than I can chew, but I would like to start wrapping my head around it for the future. Eventually I'd like to use object detection as opposed to template matching -- but I'll figure that out later.

I have looked into multithreading and multiprocessing and I think that either could get the job done, but I wanted to ensure I was on the right track.

Thanks

Edit: could/should I just import that variable using 
from screengrabber.py import locations

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible to share state between processes using [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) or [proxy objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). The docs have some good examples showing how to get multiple processes to share the same data.